# Impossible to create a new account on prestashop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, prestashop

I am currently developping a new website

When I am trying to create an account, I get an error like this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of null.
```

And this is the code

```
function submitFunction()
    {
    $('#create_account_error').html('').hide();
    //send the ajax request to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseUri,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        data: {
            controller: 'authentication',
            SubmitCreate: 1,
            ajax: true,
            email_create: $('#email_create').val(),
            back: $('input[name=back]').val(),
            token: token
        },
        success: function(jsonData)
        {
            if (jsonData.hasError())
            {
                var errors = '';
                for(error in jsonData.errors)
                    //IE6 bug fix
                    if(error != 'indexOf')
                        errors += '<li>'+jsonData.errors[error]+'</li>';
                $('#create_account_error').html('<ol>'+errors+'</ol>').show();
            }
            else
            {
                // adding a div to display a transition
                $('#center_column').html('<div id="noSlide">'+$('#center_column').html()+'</div>');
                $('#noSlide').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#noSlide').html(jsonData.page);
                    // update the state (when this file is called from AJAX you still need to update the state)
                    bindStateInputAndUpdate();
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                        document.location = '#account-creation';
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to load form.\n\nDetails:\nError thrown: " + XMLHttpRequest + "\n" + 'Text status: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

It seems to be the jsonData, on the function, which is not working as well. Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Try `if (jsonData && jsonData.hasError && jsonData.hasError())`

Comment: doesn't work, i get a blank page + "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of null"

Answer (score 2):

The success handler will be passed the data returned from the ajax request.

It will not have a function called `hasError()` because it is just a json object it will not have any functions.

The error handler should be fired if there is an http error i.e. if the ajax call returns an http 500.

I'm not familiar with prestashop, but looking over the [prestashop documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+jQuery+and+Ajax) hasError is returned as a bool (not a function), so instead try (without the parenthesis).

`if (jsonData.hasError)`

You may also want to check if any data is returned first.

`if (jsonData)`

Comment: i remove parentheses indeed, it shoul be better, but there is still the same problem...

Comment: It sounds as though your ajax call isn't returning any data. The `if(jsonData)` will check that first. I'd expect it to drop into the error function if there was a server-side error. Perhaps use the network tab of your browsers developer tools (chrome toolbar, firebug etc) to see what the ajax request is doing.